# How to rescale vector field onto a different grid?

Tags: matlab

I currently have a vector field that looks something like this, generated with the following basic structure, where Z is some matrix:

```matlab
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y)

[grad_x, grad_y] = gradient(Z)

quiver(X,Y,grad_x,grad_y)
```

[image]

I would like for this plot to be rescaled, such that the x-axis ranges from 1.5 to 3.8 and the y-axis ranges from 100 to 250, but for the arrows themselves to look identical. The only difference in the figure should be the axes labels.

I have tried:

```matlab
grad_x_rescaled = [(grad_x - min(grad_x))./(max(grad_x)-min(grad_x))].*(3.8-1.5);
grad_y_rescaled = [(grad_y - min(grad_y))./(max(grad_y)-min(grad_y))].*(250-100);
```

But the problem with this is that although the grad_x and grad_y get rescaled overall, the scaling of the arrows themselves relative to each other are not conserved, and results in below (note the thick black streaks are presumably arrowheads, but the important thing is that the direction and relative sizes of the arrows are not exactly like in the first case. 
[image]

Is there a matlab function or an expression to renormalize data into a new range, but such that the renormalized data is scaled relative to itself (such as the arrows should be scaled the same relative to one another)?

Answer (score 1):

To simply change the axes tick labels you could use Matlab's ability [to specify tick marks and tick labels](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html). Basically you would just tell Matlab where to put the ticks and what the labels should say like this:

```
xticks(linspace(0,1,6))
xticklabels(linspace(1.5,3.8,6))
yticks(linspace(0,1,6))
yticklabels(linspace(100,250,6))
```

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo thanks for the comment. I changed the answer accordingly.